# Pegando dados específicos de um "(response.body)"

Tags: flutter, dart

**Tenho esse código:**

```
class _EstabelecimentosPageState extends State<EstabelecimentosPage> {
  final String url = codeUrl;

@override void 
 initState() {
  super.initState();
  this.getJsonData();
 }

 Future<String> getJsonData() async {
  var response = await http.get(url);
  print("return " + response.body);
  setState(() {
   var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
   var data = convertDataToJson['data']['codigo'];
   return data;
  });

 return "Success";
 }
}
```

Que retorna um

```
{"status":"success","data":{"codigo":"código"}}
```

Preciso pegar só o "código" dentro do "data", mas não estou conseguindo, desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda, sou iniciante e isso está me dando me dando nos nervos porque acho que é um erro simples, mas não consigo encontrar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Consegui:**

```
Future<String> getJsonData() async {
 var response = await http.get(url);
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
   var data = convertDataToJson['data']['codigo'];
   print(data);
   return data;
 } else {
   throw ('error ${response.statusCode}');
 }
}
```